# dynamic elements with multiple upload file

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

Hi I am using http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/ for multiple upload file.
But I need the same feature for some dynamic `file` uploader also. so I crated a function `addElement()` for that. The problem is the dynamic element is creating correctly but multiple upload feature is not working.

```
<title>Add Element</title>
<script language="javascript">
this.num = 1;
function addElement(){
$top = document.getElementById('top');
newId = document.createElement('div');
id = 'my'+this.num;
newId.setAttribute('id', id );
newId.innerHTML = "<input type='file' name='DocumentFiles2' class='multi' />";
$top.appendChild(newId);
this.num++;
 }
function removedThis( id ){
var d = document.getElementById('top');
d.removeChild(id);
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' name='DocumentFiles[]' class='multi' /><!-- This one is working -->
<input type="button" name="button" value="Add Element" onclick="addElement()"  />
<div id="top" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is any alternative way to do this or make this to work.?

Comment: where is your upload code. you need to upload it by a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code after calling `addElement` and `removedThis` and check

```
function addElement(){
     .....
     .....
     reinit();
}
function removedThis( id ){
     .....
     .....
     reinit();
}
function reinit()
{
    $('input[name="DocumentFiles[]"]').MultiFile({
    // your code
    });
}
```

Comment: can u  please tell me exactly where..?

Comment: No Rohan same result there is any alternative way for this ..?

Comment: Rohan I changed DocumentFiles[] to DocumentFiles2[] now its working.. great :-)

Comment: The problem is in your `addElement` function the line `newId.innerHTML = "<input type='file' name='DocumentFiles2' class='multi' />";` should be like `newId.innerHTML = "<input type='file' name='DocumentFiles[]' class='multi' />";`